# enable wireless connection in cmd line

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, connection

I have a lenovo, and from time to time, the wireless connection gets turned off for no apparent reason (or maybe windows wants to save some battery for me).

In order to turn it back on, I need to click on the network connections icon, go to my wireless adapter, click on diagnose... Then windows will tell me the the wireless capability has been turned off, and whether I want to fix it. I click on yes, and it's fixed.

I was wondering if there a command prompt that can quickly turn in on without going through the whole hassle I usually go through?

Please advise

Comment: Too much missing information to answer this question, and it is not ontopic for [so].  You should *delete this question and ask on [su]*.  When you do, specify what operating system you are running, and in a perfect world what wifi card you have

Comment: netsh wlan connect ssid=<your SSID>

Comment: See `netsh wlan connect ?` for other options, too.